# How to write a Select with subquery in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, cakephp

I have the following query:

```
$queryResult = $this->Hit->query(
    "select P, count(S) as S
    from 
    (
        select pattern_id as P, srn as S from hits 
        where job_id=".$id." and srn != ''
        group by srn, pattern_id 
        order by pattern_id, srn
    ) as T 
        group by P
        order by P;"
);
```

So basically I have a `select .. from (select .. ) ...` statement.
It's working perfect while I'm using MySQL. But I have to migrate the DB to PostgreSQL so I would like to change this to the Cake-way. So my question is, how can I interpret this type of query (`select from select`) in **CakePHP**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got any error or not working this query?

Comment: As I mentioned it is working now. But I would like to express it on the 'Cake'-way if there is an option for this, because I will migrate the whole database to PostgreSQL and I did not check out yet whether this MySQL query will work there or not.
So I want to use something like `$this->Hit->find(...` instead of `$this->Hit->query(...`.

Comment: look at simple subquery bakery here: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lucaswxp/2011/02/11/easy_and_simple_subquery_cakephp

Comment: Thank you, I've checked this out. Unfortunately I still don't see how can I use subquery as the source table. In this case on which Model should I call the find? Or should I add the subquery to the `'table'` parameter of the find method?

Comment: Ordinarily for a query of that form you _would_ use query. I don't know if I'm misreading the query - do you _need_ that query structure? Can't it be written as a single select statement?

Comment: That could be also a solution to use a single select statement, but I didn't find a way yet to express it with one select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by interpret this query in CakePHP since your code is valid CakePHP.

That being said, I would rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT pattern_id as P, COUNT(DISTINCT srn) as S
FROM hits
WHERE job_id=".$id." and srn != ''
GROUP BY pattern_id
ORDER BY pattern_id;
```

*(I believe this is equivalent - you could load sqlfiddle.com with sample data for better testing)*

If that works and you have a Hits model, then you could re-write the query using the find method.

Comment: I wanted to interpret it on a way that using `$this->find` instead of `$this->query`.
The query you wrote works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Would be a better answer if you added the equivalent find call to it.